# Windows 10 updates drivers for FTDI

Tags: usb, serial, ftdi, windows

I have one question about the following products:
[foca-v2-2-ft232rl-tiny-breakout-usb-to-serial-uart](http://www.exp-tech.de/foca-v2-2-ft232rl-tiny-breakout-usb-to-serial-uart-interface?___SID=U)
[sparkfun-ftdi-basic-breakout-3-3v](http://www.exp-tech.de/sparkfun-ftdi-basic-breakout-3-3v?___SID=U)

I bought them last year and after time without using them I tried theses days. They seemed to be broken somehow so I researched and found this link:
[ftdi-drivers-break-fake-chips-again](http://hackaday.com/2016/02/01/ftdi-drivers-break-fake-chips-again/)

This is the problem I face. My FTDI breakouts are now completely worthless because of a windows update.

Any idea how to make them work?

I am using Windows 10, so disabling the windows updates is not a "valid" option. It can only be done by sh****-tricky registry modifications for the network.

Comment: You could unsolder the chip and replace it with an FTDI chip from somewhere like Digikey that's unlikely to have fake chips.

Comment: I didn't thought Itea or sparkfun could have fake chips ...

Comment: I'm not familiar with the supplier above but give it's open hardware I'm sure some end up getting them made elsewhere at the cheapest possible price. Plus even reputable places probably get stung by their contract manufacturers using fake parts to cut costs. But really best thing is probably just to complain to the place you bought it from.

Comment: You are right, I already sent an email to the store asking about this issue and if all their products would be "disabled" by windows update.

Comment: The current update doesn't break them. It makes them spit out a single line of text.

Comment: @Passerby what do you mean? The "NO GENUINE DEVICE FOUND" ?

Comment: http://zeptobars.com/en/read/FTDI-FT232RL-real-vs-fake-supereal%20this%20deep-down

Comment: This is the reason to absolutely avoid products from FTDI. Their behavior is absolutely unacceptable. Buy products that use UART chips from different manufacturers which don't make such moves. Like CH340, CP210x, PL2303HX, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting error 10 then there is plenty of solutions out there in the wild of the internets. The solution I have used with success is to uninstall the driver and then manually install older version which supports your system. Somehow windows doesn't update the driver I downloaded.

Comment: I get the "NO GENUINE DEVICE FOUND". I uninstalled the driver and installed and older version. Then I plugged it and was "well-recognized" . Sadly after 2 minutes windows decided to install again an updated and stopped working.

Comment: :/ or maybe it got overwritten - I didn't use the device in quite some time, instead using STM Nucleo this way